# How to add record for all the column in table

Tags: sql

I have two tables e.g:

```
Table1ID   Name    visitAreaCode
   1        test1     003
   2        test2     003
   3        test5     004


Table2ID Table1ID  BingID
    1       2       2


Table3 BingID
  1       1
  2       2
  3       2
```

If visitAreaCode from table1 are not present in table2 (by Table1ID) then the query should add all of them. In table2 BindID 1 does not exists so when executing this query BingID 1 should be linked with all the areacode starts with 003. Table 2 should then look like:

```
Table2ID Table1ID  BingID
    1       3         2
    2       1         1
    3       2         1
```

I can use `IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ...` but this will only add one record not all the records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am correctly understanding you question then try this:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (Table1ID, BingID)
  SELECT t1.Table1ID, t3.BingID FROM Table1ID as t1, Table3 as t3
  WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT * FROM Table2 as t2
      WHERE t2.Table1ID = t1.Table1ID AND t2.BingID = t3.BingID
    )
```

Assuming that Table2.Table2ID is autoincrement